# visual studio code keyboard shortcut get keybindings.json

Tags: visual-studio-code

Vscode `keybindings.json` gets generated only when you change at least one keyboard shortcut, to save only the modified keys, at `%appdata%\roaming\code\user`.

How can I get the default `keybindings.json` file? with all the default keyboard shortcuts?

Comment: if you don't modify a keybinding the keyboard shortcut page shows them all

Comment: I found it here https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For version >1.34.0,

1. Click File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts
2. There is a triple-dot (...) at the top-right hand corner. Click on that. (the More Actions menu)
3. Select "Show Default Keybindings".

you can also refer to:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_viewing-modified-keybindings

or,

you can probably refer to https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings

Comment: I actually wanted the file itself, to be able to import it to visual studio ide, to use the vscode keyboard shortcuts, since using the "visual studio code" keyboard scheme in the settings is not working for all keys.

Comment: https://github.com/codebling/vs-code-default-keybindings Does this help?